# How to find conditional sum in R based on positive and negative values

Tags: r, list, cumsum

I have this list where I need to do a conditional sum over the positive and negative values. I could do this with data table using this. But I'm looking for a base R solution.

```
list1 = list(
    x=c(1,1,-1,-1,1),
    y=c(-1,-1,1,-1,-1)
    )

lapply(list1, function(x) ave(x, rleid(x), FUN = cumsum))

$x
[1]  1  2 -1 -2  1

$y
[1] -1 -2  1 -1 -2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rle` in `base R` to create the group for `ave` by `rep`licating the sequence of 'values' with the `lengths` created with `rle`

```
lapply(list1, function(x) ave(x, with(rle(x),
         rep(seq_along(values), lengths)), FUN = cumsum))
#$x
#[1]  1  2 -1 -2  1

#$y
#[1] -1 -2  1 -1 -2
```

---

Or another option is to check the difference of adjacent elements (for numeric), then do the cumulative sum to create the group

```
lapply(list1, function(x) ave(x,  cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(x) != 0)) , FUN = cumsum))
```

Or for a general case, just remove the first and last elements, do a comparison to create the group

```
lapply(list1, function(x) ave(x, cumsum(c(TRUE, head(x, -1)
             != tail(x, -1))), FUN = cumsum))
```

Comment: Also would this be the fastest way to solve this as i have a long list.

Comment: @ChirayuChamoli `rle` is very fast, but you can also create by `cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(x) != 0))`

Comment: please include it in your anwser it will be more informative. thanks again so much

Comment: yea i did there was question only for positive values tho leave out other values which were 0.